# Error: "The conversion of the nvarchar value ' 92012156148' overflowed an int column"

Tags: c#, sql

Lo que estoy tratando de hacer es capturar en un textbox el número de identificación de una persona, guardar el valor en una variable, buscarlo en la base de datos y mostrar el nombre en label.

Este es el código:

```
SqlConnection conexion = new SqlConnection("server=N ; database=CITISALUD ; integrated security = true");
            conexion.Open();
            string cc = TextBox1.Text;
            string cadena = "select Nombre1, Nombre2, Apellido1, Apellido2 from Pacientes where Documento=" + (cc);
            SqlCommand comando = new SqlCommand(cadena, conexion);
            SqlDataReader registro = comando.ExecuteReader();
            if (registro.Read())
            {
                Label1.Text = registro["Nombre1"].ToString();
                Label2.Text = registro["Nombre2"].ToString();
                Label3.Text = registro["Apellido1"].ToString();
                Label4.Text = registro["Apellido2"].ToString();
            }
            else
                Label5.Text = "No Existe";
            conexion.Close();
```

Pero me sale este error:

> ```
> Se produjo la excepción System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException.
> HResult=0x80131904
> Mensaje = The conversion of the nvarchar value ' 92012156148' overflowed an int column.
> Origen = .Net SqlClient Data Provider
> Seguimiento de la pila:
> <No se puede evaluar el seguimiento de la pila de excepciones>
> ```

El campo de la tabla es tipo nvarchar.

---

Gracias por tu ayuda¡¡¡

1. Ya modifique el Data Source. ok
2. Cambie el código como me dijiste y sale este error. 
   [image: este es el error]
   revisando intente con este otro y no me mostró ningún error ¡¡¡

> Documento =  ' + cc ' "

Ejecuto la aplicación y no me muestra ningún error, Pero tampoco me filtra  por el documento que es lo que intento hacer, entra al if por que tengo un mensaje de que si no encuentra el documento me diga que no existe.

[image: No arroja el resultado que espero]
espero me puedan ayudar y muchas gracias por lo que me han ayudado.

Answer (score 4):

El error que tienes es porque intentas asignar un valor a un entero que se pasa de su rango.

Usa el tipo bigInt.

```
rango del entero: 4 bytes: -2.147.483.648 a 2.147.483.647
rango del bigInt: 8 bytes: -2^63 a 2^63-1
```

Tu número es el 92.012.156.148, el cual se pasa del valor máximo que puede guardar un entero y por eso te da el error.

Debes de cambiar el tipo de dato a bigInt. Si crees que los valores en otras columnas pueden exceder el rango, cambia su tipo de datos también.

Respuesta sacada de https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23191472/conversion-of-the-nvarchar-value-3001822585-overflowed-an-int-column propuesta por @Mudassir Hasan